# SVG: how to position bounding box of rotated text

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I have to build a SVG image containing some rotated text elements. I want to achieve the following:

- Each text element shall be rotated around its center point by `a` degree.
- The resulting (imaginary) bounding box of the rotated text shall be translated, so that it's upper left is at position `x,y`.
- We don't know the content, i.e., the width, of the text elements beforehand.

What is the best way to do that?

(I have a basic understanding of SVG and I am able to look up the spec on my own. So I know about `transform` and `rotate()`, `translate()`... However, I struggle with this specific case.)

Comment: This question is pretty much just about webpage layout, and thus probably belongs on doctype. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @TED Actually he wants to calculate the bounding box after the rotation, I think the only way to do it is in code: http://doctype.com/svg-position-bounding-box-rotated-text